# Python requests_html sleep to render Dynamic HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use requests_html to wait 16 seconds before the js on an HTML page renders dynamic HTML. Can you help me? ss.contents is returning empty but I can print hardcoded HTML from the #spellbook div.

```
import keyboard    
from requests_html import HTMLSession    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

url = 'https://dubioustunic.github.io/spinning-sword/philosophersstone'    
s = HTMLSession()    
response = s.get(url)    
response.html.render(sleep = 16)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')    
ss = soup.find("div", {"id": "spellbook"})      
keyboard.write(ss.contents[0])
```

edit: don't tell me to use selenium it's not working b/c of remnants of Bill Gates' old Monopoly

Comment: What about Playwright or Puppeteer instead of Selenium?

Comment: Puppeteer should definitely work, AKX.

Comment: can you help me make a time delay in pyppeteer this is my idea, which is wrong
response = session.get(url=url)
time.sleep(32);
response.html.render()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself I used Playwright.

Full code:

```
import time
import sys
import pyautogui
import keyboard
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import asyncio
import pyppeteer
from promise import Promise
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# 主要是重写HTMLSession类
# HTMLSession类是用来包装pyppeteer的,添加参数的也是在pyppeteer里面
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
```

#Hall the horizon, whilst he saileth, saileth towards the "east side of heaven, his #sister figure of Mut painted upon a piece of linen, and over the figures of two
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

```
count = 0;

while(True):
    count += 1;
    print(count);
    pyautogui.click(201, 555)
    async def run(playwright):
        chromium = playwright.chromium
        browser = await chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        for current_url in ["https://dubioustunic.github.io/spinning-sword/philosophers_stone"]:
            await page.goto(current_url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")
            element = await page.wait_for_selector("#spellbook")
            keyboard.write(await element.inner_text())
        await browser.close()

#IN ALL THE EARTH . CHAPTER CLXIV. [From Lepsius, Todtenbnch, Bl . 78.] Vignette #: A goddess, to the West, stretch "out thy hand to Teta,  
async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
await run(playwright)
    asyncio.run(main())
    #session = HTMLSession2()
    #session.browser
    #response = session.get(url=url)    
    #response.html.render(sleep = 66)#OPTIMUS PRIME
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    #ss = soup.find("div", {"id": "spellbook"})
    #print(ss.contents);

    time_start = time.time()
    seconds = 0
    minutes = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds = int(time.time() - time_start) - minutes * 60#YHVH
     #HEAT TO BE UNDER clean with bet incense and "natron ; no member of thine #hath any the ordering of my "'territory .'" The same idea   
        if seconds==1:          
            pyautogui.click(900,340);
            break;
            #sys.exit();    
    time.sleep(37);
```